# Compiled dll from one app doesn't work in other

Tags: c#, dll

I have two apps. They share common features and addons. To be compatible, both are using same namespace structure. The apps loads addons as cs and compiles them to dll.

Same addons as cs works in both apps - loaded from the source and compiled to dll. On the next run, the apps load the dll files only.

I want to allow distribution of addons as dll only without the source code. The problem is that if a dll is compiled form the first app, it cannot be loaded from the second.

On the image below, I have "Adaptable MACD" compiled form each app separately.

[image: Comparing Manifests]
When I try to load the first, from the second app, I receive the following error message:

"*Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.*"

This is my code:

```
public void LoadDllIndicator(string dllPath, out string errorMessages)
{
    errorMessages = string.Empty;
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
    try
    {
        Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            if (!typeof (IIndicator).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                continue;

            var newIndicator = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Indicator;

            if (newIndicator == null)
            {
                errorMessages = "Cannot load: " + dllPath;
                return;
            }

            newIndicator.Initialize(SlotTypes.NotDefined);
            newIndicator.CustomIndicator = true;
            newIndicator.LoaddedFromDll = true;
            IntegrateIndicator(dllPath, out errorMessages, newIndicator);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        errorMessages = "ERROR: Loading '" + Path.GetFileName(dllPath) + "': " + exception.Message;
        if (exception.InnerException != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(exception.InnerException.Message))
            errorMessages += " " + exception.InnerException.Message;
    }
}
```

How to make possible, dll compiled form one of the apps to work in the other?

Comment: [Link to the full sized image of Manifests](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix3xZ.jpg)

Comment: Aren´t you loading dll in exlusive mode in first app ? Because than it can not be loaded in second one

Comment: Is it being used by both apps at the sane time?

Comment: I'm using LoadDllIndicator method shown above in both apps. I copy and paste the dll to the second app. They do not use the same file.

Comment: The code crashes at: Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

Comment: I printout the LoaderExceptions:

Could not load file or assembly 'Forex Strategy Builder, Version=2.98.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It seams that the the app that compiled the dll "Forex Strategy Builder" is referenced in the dll.

Comment: One library seems to be part of Forex Software, and another is your project built in VS2010. Because of this your sentence 'the apps loads addons as cs and compiles them to dll' makes very little sense to me. Could you give more details?

Comment: "Forex Strategy Builder" compiles "Adaptable MACD.dll". Later, I copy "Adaptable MACD.dll" to "Forex Strategy Trader"'s Libraries folder and I want to load it.

What I noticed is that it requires "'Forex Strategy Builder, Version=2.98.0.0" - the application that has compiled the dll. I'm using reflections to add ReferencedAssemblies to the CompilerParameters when compile the dll. Probably the dll searches a reference form the first assembly. !?

Comment: Maybe Forex Strategy Builder app changes the source .cs before compiling it, adding some code that relies on functionality provided by the app itself. So, it's not just the reference that is required, but some functionality as well.

Comment: The code that compiles and loads dll in "Forex Strategy Builder" is identical with the code in "Forex Strategy Trader". I even made the namespaces the same. The dll source code compiles in both apps successfully. Probably  "Forex Strategy Builder" adds more 'unused' references to the dll by using reflection: [Adding Referenced Assemblies](http://s21.postimg.org/ubjh6iyev/screenshot_11.png)

Comment: The full code is in [GitHub Project](https://github.com/PopovMP/Forex-Strategy-Builder/tree/master/Source/ForexStrategyBuilder/IndicatorCompiler)

Comment: Is it possible, despite of the same namespaces, the dll to want references to the exact app that build it, instead of the same classes from the app that loads it?